# How to query postgres to get data in json format?

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image]

From the table I want to select users firstname and lastname only if their age is greater than 10 in a json format.

So the output of the query should be

[image]

I could select create a json text from but not sure how to apply where clause for `Key = 'AGE' and value > 10`

Here is my query

```
select json_object_agg(key,value) from table where key in ('firstname','lastname')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an aggregate with a `FILTER` clause:

```
SELECT id,
       json_object_agg(key, value) AS json,
FROM mytable
GROUP BY id
HAVING (max(value::integer) FILTER (WHERE key = 'AGE')) > 10;
```

Comment: but it should be value of E only

Comment: I don't understand. Maybe you can edit the question and explain it. What is the logic?

Comment: I edited the question. Let me know if it makes sense.

Comment: Ok, answer improved.

Comment: The problem is first inner query is executed on mytable which is huge and then filtered on the result. The inner query takes lot of time to execute. Would there be any other way to do the same thing?

Comment: Are there only few `id`s with age > 10? If yes, it could be improved using an index. If not, you can't gain much.